# CiviCRM has not bootstrapped sufficiently to fire event "hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities"

Tags: drupal-8

After upgrading CiviCRM to civicrm-asset-plugin 1.1, civicrm-core 5.29.1, civicrm-drupal-8 5.29.1,  and civicrm-packages 5.29.1 I started getting   "CiviCRM has not bootstrapped sufficiently to fire event "hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities"." In trying to diagnose the problem I upgraded civicrm_entity to the newest commit (9f69c64).

I upgraded the code with Composer and everything appeared to work correctly.  The CiviCRM upgrade was done with CV and the upgrade reported to be done successfully.

I appreciate any help in how to approach this.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an almost identical error today (`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: CiviCRM has not bootstrapped sufficiently to fire event "hook_civicrm_entityTypes".`).  In my case, there were some file permission issues, and resetting the file permissions solved my problem.  I believe my PHP user had access to the files but my Apache user did not.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a change in 5.29. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17831. It's signalling that somehow something isn't working with the way either the civicrm_entity module is setting the hook now or something about that change isn't working as expected. I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 0):

could you detail the process to rest the the file permissions ?
I am having the same issue that is revealed by `drush updb -v`.

`In CiviEventDispatcher.php line 190: [RuntimeException] CiviCRM has not bootstrapped sufficiently to fire event "hook_civicrm_alter_drupal_entities".`

I also thing that it is related to `civicrm_entity` as there is `Exception trace:`
  `at /path/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:190 Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch() at /path/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:167 CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke() at /path/web/modules/contrib/civicrm_entity/src/SupportedEntities.php:867 Drupal\civicrm_entity\SupportedEntities::alterEntityInfo() at /path/web/modules/contrib/civicrm_entity/src/SupportedEntities.php:707 Drupal\civicrm_entity\SupportedEntities::getInfo() at /path/web/modules/contrib/civicrm_entity/civicrm_entity.module:54 civicrm_entity_entity_type_build() at /path/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php:129`